# Docked menu on scroll - JavaScript probably required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/usbs2/19/

I'm trying to make it so when I scroll down, the yellow menu becomes docked to the top of the page when you scroll down from it, I'm sure you have seen the kind of thing before, something like this:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/PersistantHeaders/

I know it is possible to make a header docked all the time, but how do you make it so it is only there when scrolling down enough to make it go off the page. Im guessing it would need some kind of jquery magic?

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">test</div>
    <div id="jumbo">test</div>
    <div id="select">menu</div>
    <div id="features">1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/usbs2/23/)

You can use jQuery, with a slight change to your CSS:

```
// get initial top position of menu
var init = $('#select').offset().top;
// listen to window scroll event
$(window).scroll(function () {
    // if top of window scrolled past top of menu
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > init) {
        // fix the menu to the top of the page
        $('#select').css({
            top: 0,
            position: 'fixed'
        });
    } else {
        // otherwise put it back in its regular position
        $('#select').css('position','relative');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%; /* <-- defined default width */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 60px;
    background: pink;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#jumbo {
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
#select {
    height: 60px;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:100%; /* <-- set width (relative to body) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `position:fixed;` to the `#header` like [so](http://jsfiddle.net/usbs2/20/) it will be automatically kept at the top. If the header doesn't need to be at the top all times (like when there is something above the header that is allowed to scroll off screen) you might need a script to add or remove a class containing this css property.

The other answer uses jQuery, this is the non-jQuery version of it:

```
var select = document.querySelector('#select');
var initialPosition = select.offsetTop;
addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (window.scrollY > initialPosition) {
        select.classList.add('fixed');
    } else if (select.classList.contains('fixed')) {
        select.classList.remove('fixed');
    }
});
```

And of course add the class to your stylesheet:

```
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usbs2/27/) showing the working script